# Javascript access member variables by reference

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, scope, pass-by-reference

I'm writing a javascript app where I'd like to access my application variables at a global scope. Something like this:

```
//Initialize 
var myApp=new app();

//Count is zero here, as expected since app is asynchronous
console.log(myApp.count);

//But 5 seconds later, count should have a non-zero value
setTimeout(function(){ 
    console.log(myApp.count); 
}, 5000);
```

And the application code:

```
//Application code
function app() {

    var count=0;

    setTimeout(function(){ 
        console.log("Setting count to 10");
        count=10;
    }, 2500);

    //Member variable for count
    this.count=count;
}
```

See the jsfiddle here:
https://jsfiddle.net/o4db2ep4/

What I want is for the first access of count to be zero, but the second one should be 10.

I think what is happening is that at the time I'm declaring myApp, it obtains the value for count as zero. It's like a pass by value/reference problem combined with scope and I'm struggling with this.

How can I get a reference to app.count that is dynamic, i.e. always contains the current values of count, and not the value at the time of the assignment? If this isn't possible, how should I re-think this problem?

Comment: `setTimeout` doesn't pause the script. It just schedules the function you provide it to be run later, so `this.count = count` is executed long before the `setTimeout` callback gets exectued.

Comment: Yes, I understand this. But if app.count is a pointer to this.count, then they will reference the same values all of the time, regardless of when things are run.

Comment: JavaScript is strictly pass/assign by value. A variable / property cannot reference another variable / property.

Comment: Well, this isn't strictly true since with an array of objects, the array contents are assigned by reference (not by value). Hence the need for deep copies, slice() etc.

Comment: @jrel: You are confusing object references with pass by reference. That's a common mistake. Pass / assign by reference is only about how *bindings* related to each other, not *values*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is happening is that `count` and `this.count` are different variables, and they are not magically in sync. Once you assigned it it is a one-time thing. When it gets assigned `this.count=count=0`; the timeout will happen 2500ms after that at which point what you want to update is `this.count`:

```
function app() {

    this.count = 0;

    setTimeout(function(){ 
        console.log("Setting count to 10");
        this.count = 10;
    }.bind(this), 2500);
}
```

You don't need both variables as you can see above.

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful. It's the .bind(this) that is doing the real magic, and this solves the issue. But I have to admit I'm not sure exactly what it is doing.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
//Initialize 
var myApp=new app();
myApp.increment(myApp);

//Count is zero here, as expected since app is asynchronous
console.log(myApp.count);

//But 5 seconds later, count does have a non-zero value
setTimeout(function(){ 
     console.log(myApp.count); 
}, 5000);


//Application code
function app() {

    this.count=0;

    this.increment = function(obj) {
      setTimeout(function(){ 
          console.log("Setting count to 10");
          if (typeof(obj.count)=='undefined') { obj.count=0;}
          obj.count+=10;
      }, 2500);    
    }
}
```